# Tikz out-degree not working properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows, tikz-arrows

Changing the out-degree value in the code below doesn't seem to be working. The figure I get always has an out-degree equal to 0. Any ideas why?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
            state/.style={fill=blue!30, circle, minimum size=0.5cm},
            transition/.style={>=stealth'},
        ]

        \node[state, label={-120:$q_1$}] (q1) {};

        \def\n{4}
        \foreach \q in {2,...,\n} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro\pq{\q-1}                       % previous node index
            \node[state, label={-120:$q_\q$}, right=of q\pq] (q\q) {};  % node
            \draw[transition, ->] (q\pq) to (q\q);                  % transition level 1

            % transition level 2
            \edef\tempa{\q}
            \edef\tempb{2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \pgfmathsetmacro\ppq{\q-2};     % 2nd previous node
                \edef\new{q\ppq};

                %%%% THIS OUT-DEGREE doesn't work
                \draw[transition, ->] (q\ppq) to[out=45, in=135] (q\q);                 
            \fi
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

At the moment, the code generates this figure:

[image]

However, I expect to get something like this:
[image]

Comment: That looks like 45 degrees to me, what do you expect to see?

Comment: I think they expected to see the arrow acting as though it is emerging from the center of the blue dot, just like the other side enters its node.

Comment: @Matt  Yes I expect to see what Paul described in his comment. I've updated my post to include a picture of what I want my final result to look like.

Comment: It seems like it is working properly, however when you use `(q\ppq)` tikz isn't understanding what you're referencing because it knows `q2`. I don't know how to do this drawing dynamically; is that a requirement?

Comment: @PaulStiverson Yes, the code works properly when I hard-code the node names. I need to do this dynamically because I want to use this concept in a more complicated structure which is too long to hard-code. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Here is one more [related answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14605/9335).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `\pgfmathsetmacro\ppq{\q-2};` set `\ppq` to `2.0` and `(q2.0)` is not the same as `(q2)`. To avoid this you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro\ppq{int(\q-2)};` or even better `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ppq{\q-2};` (as suggested by @percusse in the comment).

Here is an example of code (not exactly the same as yours):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      state/.style={fill=blue!30, circle, minimum size=0.5cm},
      transition/.style={>=stealth'},
    ]

    \node[state, label={-120:$q_1$}] (q1) {};

    \def\n{4}
    \foreach[evaluate={\pq=int(\q-1);\ppq=int(\q-2)}] \q in {2,...,\n} {
      \node[state, label={-120:$q_\q$}, right=of q\pq] (q\q) {};  % node
      \draw[transition, ->] (q\pq) to (q\q);                      % transition level 1
      \ifnum\q>2\relax
        \draw[transition, ->] (q\ppq) to[out=45, in=135] (q\q);   % transition level 2
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: or better `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. This must be a duplicate of at least five but couldn't find even one :)

Comment: @percusse I know, but I either was not able to find one of the thousands ... finaly I have one ;) Flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. Sorry for the duplicated. I tried searching for answers before I posted the question but couldn't find any. Must've been using the wrong search terms.

Comment: @alguru You are welcome. As you can read in the comments, finding the existing answers is not always easy ;)