# Clash between aligned environment and TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, amsmath

The following code mis-renders the multi-line label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (0,2) {B};
\draw (A) to node [anchor=east, align=right] {my\\multi-line\\label} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It's all the fault of the `aligned` environment - which, however, is necessary to get the equation number to typeset in the proper place with respect to the diagram.

So: is this a weird interaction bug? Can it be solved? Or is there a hack that just lets me align my picture using a different method to avoid this strange issue? Or perhaps my TikZ is buggy, or this isn't the correct way to do multi-line labels.

Screenshot with code as above:
[image: screenshot with code as given]

Screenshot without aligned environment:
[image: screenshot without aligned environment]

Comment: Do you have a complete MWE of "the equation" you mention? I'm pretty sure it can be resolved without "blaming" the `aligned` environment. `:)`

Comment: Using `split` instead of `aligned` seems to help, but the line spacing is a little different.

Comment: An image which shows the incorrect behavior would also be very good.

Comment: Hi Werner - I've given a MWE in the question! Typeset it with and without the `aligned` environment and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: i'll wait to see the answers before saying whether this is or is not likely to be a bug; it certainly seems to be the result of unfortunate interaction.  all i can say for sure at the moment is that tikz didn't exist when amsmath was created, and to the best of my knowledge, no one has ever explicitly tested the two packages together in this way.  i'll check back later.

Comment: If the only thing that you use the `aligned` environment for is the numbering, you could take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14599/86 which provides a pure TikZ way of putting in equation numbers (the code is at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files as `tikzeqnos.tex` but as the file extension suggests, I haven't worked on it much since the original code.  My converting-answers-to-packages time recently has been taken up with some random knot package. Maybe I should switch to the equation number one for a while ...)

Comment: @AndrewStacey But knot package is also an impressive one though :)

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\tabular{r|} \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\makebox[0pt]{A}}\\
  my \\ multi-line \\ label \\
             \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\makebox[0pt]{B}} 
\endtabular
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just change `aligned` into `gathered`:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (0,2) {B};
\draw (A) to node [anchor=east, align=right] {my\\multi-line\\label} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Actually, `gathered` (as well as `aligned`) changes the line spacing, so maybe you'll prefer to use a `gathered*` environmen defined as

```
\newenvironment{gathered*}{\gathered\openup-1\jot}{\endgathered}
```

Actually, a simpler solution might be to say

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (0,2) {B};
\draw (A) to node [anchor=east, align=right] {my\\multi-line\\label} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution, so I like it the most - but it affects the line spacing!

Comment: @JamieVicary Just like `aligned`. I'll add a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Would "boxing" the "my multiline label" work? Boxing here refers to placing the contents in a `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (0,5) {B};
\draw (A) to node [anchor=east] {\begin{tabular}{r@{}}my\\[\jot]multi-line\\[\jot]label\end{tabular}} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Using a `r@{}` column specification for the `tabular` removes the column separation on the right, providing a similar alignment as obtained with `align=right`. `\\[\jot]` spreads out the `tabular` lines, similar to renewing `\arraystretch`, but allows for line-by-line control. Use it if needed.

Comment: The boxing isn't necessary, you could just put the `tabular` directly in the node.